# Linear quadratic regulator via least squares

Tags: convex-optimization, control-theory, least-squares, optimal-control, dynamic-programming

In [this](http://stanford.edu/class/ee363/lectures/dlqr.pdf) set of slides, the finite horizon LQR problem is stated as a least-squares problem (slide 11), and using a naive method (e.g., QR factorization), the cost to solve this problem is $O(N^3nm^2)$ (slide 12). However, it is also said that a less naive method would cost $O(Nn^3)$ (slide 13). What would be a less naive method
?

Comment: A factorization method which exploits banded structure in a generic setting.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg could you point me to some material where this approach is discussed?

Comment: No, not my field so I don't have any particular references. Googloing the topic brings up loads of material